# how to make scrollable axis/ pan along x-axis in d3js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, scroll, zooming

I am trying to create a timeline chart using D3.js in angularjs with the option to scroll the along the x-axis to view data.

```
var rawSvg = element.find("svg")[0];

var width = 1000, height = 300;
var svg = d3.select(rawSvg)
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);


// scale for x and y axis
var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(), 5)]).range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([28, 0]).range([0, height-75]);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(xScale).y(yScale).scaleExtent([1,1]).on("zoom", zoomed);

// setting up axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(d3.time.hour, 3).innerTickSize(-(height-75)).outerTickSize(2);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").outerTickSize(2).ticks(0).tickFormat(function(d){
            return '';
        }).tickPadding(10);

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(20,10)").call(zoom);

// axis
g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x-axis")
            .attr("transform","translate(0,"+(height-75)+")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "center");

g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y-axis")
            .call(yAxis);


function zoomed(){
            svg.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis)
            // svg.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis)
}
```

But I am not able to achieve so.
I am getting a chart like this.

[image]

But what I want is to display the current date data and then the user should be able to scroll along the x-axis to see the past and future data.

I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://codepen.io/bennekrouf/pen/jqvqNZ?editors=0010).

**EDIT**

In the above code I was not able to capture the zoom events so I have appended a full length rectangle now I can capture the zoom events.

```
g.append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height-75)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all");
```

But still I am unable to scroll along the x-axis.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Comment: @Gunner Something like this https://codepen.io/bennekrouf/pen/jqvqNZ?editors=0010 with options like in your example to zoom on a particular event but the data will be plotted as point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny that sometimes debugging an issue might take up a lot of time but then the solution would be a **minor** spelling/selection mistake. I did spend about 40 minutes on this but it's just a small selection mistake.

This is one such case. So here' the issue:

You are applying a `class` named `x-axis` (notice the **dash** here) to the **X Axis** BUT in your `zoom` function, you're looking for axis with `.x.axis` which is not right. So here's a fork of your fiddle that resolves the issue:

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kro3woc4/)

Code Changes:

```
function zoomed(){
    svg.select('.x-axis').call(xAxis)
}
```

Also, I've changed the number of `ticks` on X axis to be every 6 hours to avoid overlapping.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks... I was stuck with that for an hour before getting it. forgot to update... I have updated the tick to 12 hours to avoid overlapping...